# SonarQube 6.0 plugin or rule-set to detect unused and dead PHP code

Tags: php, sonarqube

I tried searching for a way to detect unused and dead PHP code through sonar.
I found a plugin Useless Code Tracker Plugin at -http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Useless+Code+Tracker+Plugin

But it has been discontinued.

Has a new plugin or a rule-set been introduced for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Useless Code Tracker plugin tracked the number of duplicated lines that could be reduced/removed via consolidation. To find *unused* code, take a look at the [relevant PHP rules](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#languages=php%7Ctags=unused).